# Error: export 'getApp' (imported as 'getApp') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase

While I am trying to connect my angular project with  firebase, I am getting these errors.

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-3b632d0b.js:600:29-40 - Error: export 'SDK_VERSION' (imported as 'SDK_VERSION') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-3b632d0b.js:787:19-31 - Error: export '_getProvider' (imported as '_getProvider') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-3b632d0b.js:3033:6-17 - Error: export 'SDK_VERSION' (imported as 'SDK_VERSION') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-3b632d0b.js:12208:7-18 - Error: export 'SDK_VERSION' (imported as 'SDK_VERSION') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-3b632d0b.js:12432:7-18 - Error: export 'SDK_VERSION' (imported as 'SDK_VERSION') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-3b632d0b.js:12887:2-20 - Error: export '_registerComponent' (imported as '_registerComponent') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-3b632d0b.js:12954:2-20 - Error: 0mexport '_registerComponent' (imported as '_registerComponent') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-3b632d0b.js:12968:2-17 - Error: export 'registerVersion' (imported as 'registerVersion') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-3b632d0b.js:12970:2-17 - Error: export 'registerVersion' (imported as 'registerVersion') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-3b632d0b.js:12999:23-29 - Error: export 'getApp' (imported as 'getApp') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/auth-compat/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/index-3b632d0b.js:13000:19-31 - Error: export '_getProvider' (imported as '_getProvider') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/database-compat/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm2017.js:15564:27-33 - Error: export 'getApp' (imported as 'getApp') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/database-compat/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm2017.js:15565:9-21 - Error: export '_getProvider' (imported as '_getProvider') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/database-compat/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm2017.js:15681:16-29 - Error: export 'SDK_VERSION' (imported as 'SDK_VERSION$1') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/database-compat/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm2017.js:15683:2-20 - Error: export '_registerComponent' (imported as '_registerComponent') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/database-compat/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm2017.js:15694:2-17 - Error: export 'registerVersion' (imported as 'registerVersion') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/database-compat/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm2017.js:15696:2-17 - Error: export 'registerVersion' (imported as 'registerVersion') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/firestore-compat/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:20787:12-24 - Error: export '_getProvider' (imported as '_getProvider') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/firestore-compat/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:20812:16-22 - Error: export 'getApp' (imported as 'getApp') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/firestore-compat/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:20813:9-21 - Error: export '_getProvider' (imported as '_getProvider') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/firestore-compat/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:21061:9-31 - Error: export '_removeServiceInstance' (imported as '_removeServiceInstance') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/firestore-compat/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:23851:4-15 - Error: export 'SDK_VERSION' (imported as 'SDK_VERSION') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/firestore-compat/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:23851:18-36 - Error: export '_registerComponent' (imported as '_registerComponent') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/firestore-compat/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:23859:17-32 - Error: export 'registerVersion' (imported as 'registerVersion') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/firestore-compat/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.esm2017.js:23860:2-17 - Error: export 'registerVersion' (imported as 'registerVersion') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/storage-compat/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/index.esm2017.js:4148:26-32 - Error: export 'getApp' (imported as 'getApp') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/storage-compat/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/index.esm2017.js:4151:26-38 - Error: export '_getProvider' (imported as '_getProvider') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/storage-compat/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/index.esm2017.js:4242:75-86 - Error: export 'SDK_VERSION' (imported as 'SDK_VERSION') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/storage-compat/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/index.esm2017.js:4246:2-20 - Error: export '_registerComponent' (imported as '_registerComponent') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/storage-compat/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/index.esm2017.js:4251:2-17 - Error: export 'registerVersion' (imported as 'registerVersion') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/storage-compat/node_modules/@firebase/storage/dist/index.esm2017.js:4253:2-17 - Error: export 'registerVersion' (imported as 'registerVersion') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/app-check/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:1454:37-49 - Error: export '_getProvider' (imported as '_getProvider') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/app-check/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:1548:37-49 - Error: export '_getProvider' (imported as '_getProvider') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/app-check/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:1701:34-40 - Error: export 'getApp' (imported as 'getApp') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/app-check/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:1704:19-31 - Error: export '_getProvider' (imported as '_getProvider') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/app-check/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:1901:2-20 - Error: export '_registerComponent' (imported as '_registerComponent') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/app-check/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:1920:2-20 - Error: export '_registerComponent' (imported as '_registerComponent') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

./node_modules/@firebase/app-check/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:1929:2-17 - Error: export 'registerVersion' (imported as 'registerVersion') was not found in '@firebase/app' (possible exports: __esModule, default, firebase)

Comment: Did you solve @Yassine? I found comments about downgrading but does not seem to work

Comment: @Yassine Did you fix it? Same issue here